Does the functional form of a perturbative Hamiltonian indicate how many nonzero terms are in energy corrections?
Suppose we add a perturbative Hamiltonian to a quantum system. In principle, we can compute high order corrections to the energy levels with perturbation theory. However, I've come across some systems which can be solved exactly with a perturbation. Then computing the corrections to the energy levels, I find the exact solution is achieved after one or two orders of perturbation theory alone, and higher order corrections vanish.
Question: Is it possible to tell at what order the energy corrections from perturbation theory will vanish, if at all? Specifically, is it possible to tell from the functional form of the Hamiltonian alone, without knowing an exact solution, and without calculating many higher order corrections?
